# Pop up dialog from menu of main parent dialog(MFC)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

@oaimac,

I am not able to read the  variable from dialog CSettings
I am not sure what is is wrong in this code

```
void CCStatsDlg::OnClickSettings()
 {   

 CSettings dlg;

if (dlg.DoModal () == IDOK)

 //Problem is here I am not getting the expected value

   {
         int m_SampleNumber = dlg.getvalue ();
   }
}
```

This i am doing in CCStatsDlg class because i need to process CSettings dialog values here. m_SampleNumber is initialized to 1024 in the CCStatsDlg class constructor.below is the getvalue() in CSettings class

```
CSettings::CSettings(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialog(CSettings::IDD, pParent)

{

  SampleNumber =2048;

}

CSettings::~CSettings()

{
}

void CSettings::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)

{
CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);

DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT_SAMPLE1, SampleNumber);

}

int CSettings::getvalue()

  {

   return SampleNumber;

  }
```

Even  if i return 2048 as SampleNumber, m_SampleNumber in CCStatsDlg is not getting which is always 1024 which was initialized in constructor

So please help me out on this. Thanks

Comment: if your variable "m_SampleNumber" is defined elsewhere, just remove the "int " string inside the "int m_SampleNumber = ..." declaration otherwise your variable will only be valid inside your if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do what you want :
x associate a function to the OnClick event of your Settings menu item (using the tabs of its property windows for example) -> this will generate automatically the function inside the MainFrm.h and .cpp files
x instantiate a member structure, or variables you want to get from your hardware inside your CCStatsDlg class .h and .cpp
x fill your variables inside the OnOK () function of your CCStatsDlg class
x add one or more functions inside your CCStatsDlg .h and .cpp files like :

```
int GetValue1()
```

x call your dialogbox with :

```
    CCStatsDlg dlg ();  
    if dlg.DoModal () == IDOK
    {
       // Here you can get your variables values once OK is clicked inside your dialog box
       int value1 = dlg.GetValue1 ()
    }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: while reading the variable some problem is there CSettings dlg;
if (dlg.DoModal () == IDOK)
    {int m_SampleNumber = dlg.getvalue ();}
This i am doing in CCStatsDlg class because i need to process CSettings dialog values here. m_SampleNumber is initialized to 1024 in the CCStatsDlg class constructor.below is the getvalue() in CSettings class                                                  int CSettings::getvalue()
{ return SampleNumber;} Even  if i return 2048 as SampleNumber, m_SampleNumber in CCStatsDlg is not getting which is always 1024 which was initaised in constructor

Comment: @Vaish I do not understand your problem. Can you edit your first post with your new code.

Answer (score 0):

so you need create new CDialog derived window and then show it.

Put this code to on click event:

```
CMySettingDialog dlg;
dlg.DoModal();
```

Some sample you can find [here](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/controls/dialogbox.htm) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619z63f5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)